# How can I sort MM-DD-YYYY dates using unix sort?

Tags: sorting, unix

Have

```
01-01-2016
08-01-2015
09-05-2015
```

Want

```
08-01-2015
09-05-2015
01-01-2016
```

Is there a way to perform a sort operation on this in unix? I'm using this command and I'm getting the "HAVE" result:

```
sort file
```

Comment: Please update your question to explain exactly how you want to do the comparisons. Are those supposed to be dates with a 2-digit year? If so, using a 4-digit year should since the problem.

Comment: Thanks Keith for the catch

Comment: Your title still says `MM-DD-YY`, but the data in your question appears to be `MM-DD-YYYY` (or is it `DD-MM-YYYY`?).

Answer (score 1):

You edited the question to change the input date representation from `MM-DD-YY` (which is still what the title says) to `MM-DD-YYYY`.

I presume that means the format is under your control. If so, the best solution is to use the standard [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format `YYYY-MM-DD`. It can be sorted directly *and* it's unambiguous; `2015-03-04` is always March 4th, never April 3rd.

If you're stuck with the `MM-DD-YY` or `MM-DD-YYYY` format, another solution is to preprocess the file with `sed` to translate it to `YYYY-MM-DD`, then do a simple `sort`, then translate it back to the required format. That's probably less efficient than [SMA's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28860738/827263), but I personally find it clearer (I've never quite figured out the `sort` command's field specification syntax).

Answer (score 0):

Use `-n` option with sort, to sort numerically like:

```
sort -n -k 1.8 -k 1.7 -k 1.5 -k 1.4 -k 1.2 -k 1.1 file
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be tidier to define the field separator? `sort -n -t\- -k 3.1 -k 1.1 -k 2.1 file`

Comment: This worked for me when the MM-DD-YYYY was flush left in the text file: `sort -n -k 1.7 -k 1.1 -k 1.4 file`.
The first `-k 1.7` sorts first by YYYY (the first digit of YYYY being the 7th character), then `-k 1.1` sorts by MM (the first digit of MM being the 1st char), then `-k 1.4` sorts by DD (the first digit of DD being the 4th char).